# React form instantly loses focus and scrolls the page when clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I have a React component named form :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

import './Form.css';

function Form() {

  const nameChange=(e)=>{
    setName(e.target.value);
  }

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  }

  const [nameVal, setName] = useState();

  const {register, handleSubmit} = useForm();

    return (
      <form className="my-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <p className="more-info">Want to leave a comment</p>
        <p className="more-info">or know more about me?</p>
        <input className="in" type="text" value={nameVal} placeholder="Name" {...register("name")} onChange={nameChange}/>
        <input className="in" type="text" value='' placeholder="Email" {...register("email")}/>
        <textarea placeholder="Comment" value='' cols="5" rows="10" {...register("comment")}/>
        <button>Send</button>
      </form>
    )
}

export default Form
```

If I click on any of the inputs or the textarea, it just immediately loses focus and if I'm down far enough scrolls back to the top of the About page.

The full app can be found at: patgrady64.netlify.com
The entire code can be found on my github: https://github.com/patrickrgrady81/my-site

if there's any other questions let me know.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: In your code, you are wrapping sections in anchor tags, like `<a href="#About" ><About/></a>` - this is not valid HTML behaviour.

Comment: In your use form, maybe try `useForm({ disableEnforceFocus: false })`?

Comment: @moonwave99 I know about this error but I really don't know how else to scroll to a certain part of my spa when clicking the navbar

Comment: @Acidic9 This did not work for me, but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @moonwave99 Thank you for that. I changed it to an onClick event and it has now worked.

Answer (score 2):

As @moonwave99 pointed out:

> In your code, you are wrapping sections in anchor tags, like `<a href="#About">`
>  - this is not valid HTML behavior.

I changed my navigation to use onClick instead of using anchor tags. This made it so that the form has now been working correctly. I never would have know the trickle down effect of using the `<a>` tag like that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using disableEnforceFocus.

Comment: Thank you. but I did try this and it did not work for me.